# SBT dependency for sparkSQL

Tags: scala, sbt

I am starting to learn spark sql I am using the following dependencies in sbt. I am getting errors

```
name := "sparkLearning"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.11.8"

val sparkVersion = "1.6.1"
val sqlVersion = "1.3.1"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % sparkVersion,
  "org.apache.spark" % "spark-sql" % sqlVersion
)
```

I am getting an error.

```
Error:Error while importing SBT project:<br/>...<br/><pre>[info] Resolving com.thoughtworks.paranamer#paranamer;2.6 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#completion;0.13.15 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#control;0.13.15 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#sbt;0.13.15 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#run;0.13.15 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt.ivy#ivy;2.3.0-sbt-48dd0744422128446aee9ac31aa356ee203cc9f4 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#test-interface;1.0 ...
[info] Resolving com.jcraft#jsch;0.1.50 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-lang#scala-compiler;2.10.6 ...
[info] Resolving jline#jline;2.14.3 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#compiler-ivy-integration;0.13.15 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#incremental-compiler;0.13.15 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#logic;0.13.15 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#main-settings;0.13.15 ...
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run 'last *:update' for the full output.
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run 'last *:ssExtractDependencies' for the full output.
[error] (*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: org.apache.spark#spark-sql;1.3.1: not found
[error] (*:ssExtractDependencies) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: org.apache.spark#spark-sql;1.3.1: not found
[error] Total time: 15 s, completed 27-Jul-2017 15:29:52
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=384M; support was removed in 8.0
```

Please let me know how to resolve this.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

correct form for you sbt file is

```
name := "sparkLearning"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.11.8"

val sparkVersion = "1.6.1"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.spark" % "spark-core_2.10" % sparkVersion,
  "org.apache.spark" % "spark-sql_2.10" % sparkVersion
  )
```

I would suggest you to use latest spark versions which should be compatible with scala 2.11.8

```
name := "sparkLearning"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.11.8"

val sparkVersion = "2.2.0"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % sparkVersion,
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % sparkVersion
  )
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Comment: thanks for the acceptance :) you can upvote too if it helped you

Comment: If you're going to use spark-submit to run your spark program, you need to add Provided to Spark dependencies:

val sparkVersion = "2.2.0"
...
    "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % sparkVersion % Provided,
    "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % sparkVersion % Provided,
...